# left join function help in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Is it possible, to lookup values via left join that have different column names in the data set, but have the same values.

For example, In dataframe x, I have a variable email but in dataframe y my column name could be username but store emails ids

```
x
email
abcd@gmail.com
efg@gmmail.com

y
username
abcd@gmail.com
xyz@gmail.com
```

This what I would have used if both x&y had same column names, but this scenario is different.

```
library(dplyr)
z <- left_join(x, y, by = "email", copy = FALSE)
```

Comment: `left_join(x, y, by = c("email" = "username"), copy = FALSE)`

Comment: From `?left_join` : "*To join by different variables on x and y use a named vector. For example, by = c("a" = "b") will match x.a to y.b.*" <sigh>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using a named vector, where the name is the x input, and the character is the y input:

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(x, y, by = c(email = "username"))
```